# Is there a way to adjust height to match the midpoint of another image?

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how I would line up an images centerpoint where two other images meet.

Basically I'm trying to do whats happening in this picture.

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/488816/screenshots/1726057/1_1x.jpg

How can I do this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, but you need to think of this the other way around.  In other words, you need to adjust the midpoint placement of the image on top so that it aligns with the bottom of the image that it is above.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/94ahLy5v/)

Assuming you have two images in a containing div and you know the size of the smaller image on top, you can position the smaller image absolutely and set the bottom property of the smaller image to exactly one half of it's height:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-group">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x300/e8117f/fff&text=Big%20Image" alt="Big Image" class="big-image" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300/9acd32/fff&text=Small%20Image" alt="Small Image" class="small-image" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-group {
    position: relative;
}
.big-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.small-image { 
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -125px; /*half the height of itself*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Another way of tackling this is that you can use transform.  The advantage here is that you don't need to know the image height.  One potential disadvantage is that the transform property is not supported in IE8 or Opera-Mini (if you care about those browsers).  Also, transform still requires prefixes to work on many browsers.  This example is using the exact same html as above.  Instead of setting the height of the image and calculating half the height for the bottom property, you just set the bottom property to 0 and then use the transform property to move the image along the y axis by 50%.  Thus, the height of the image is automatically taken into account by the transform.

## [DEMO #2](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/94ahLy5v/4/)

**CSS:**

```
.image-group {
    position: relative;
}
.big-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.small-image { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 50%);
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
```